# How to add table heading and table data in Existing PDF Report in Odoo 13?

Tags: report, odoo-13

I want to know how to add table heading and table data in Existing PDF Report using xpath or other method in odoo 13?

Does anyone know the syntax or other method in odoo 13?

Comment: refer to this [link](https://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/inheriting-and-modifying-qweb-reports/) question is vague consider deleting it for now

Answer (score 0):

It similar to making qweb template for report with slight change.Here i am inheriting stock picking report template and adding another after name of pick operation:

```
<odoo>
<template id="report_po_inherit" inherit_id="stock.report_picking">
    <xpath expr="//h1[@t-field='o.name']" position="before">
        <div t-if="o.picking_type_id.code=='incoming'">
            <h1>Heading 1 </h1>
        </div>
    </xpath>
</template>
</odoo>
```

For more and detailed explanation you can refer to this [link](https://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/inheriting-and-modifying-qweb-reports/)